# Highcharts redraw Issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on stacked area highchart with live update, we have 3 different series and every series gets updated after every 30 seconds. I am using series `addPoint` to update series as

```
series[Index].addPoint({x : xAxisVal, y : yAxisVal }, false, true,true);
```

After adding values for each series I am calling highchart `redraw` method but this method sometimes throws an exception.

here is the snap of error:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXJtE.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tvpC.png

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could You paste your complete code here ? or on fiddle?

redraw: Boolean
Defaults to true. Whether to redraw the chart after the point is added. When adding more than one point, it is highly recommended that the redraw option be set to false, and instead chart.redraw() is explicitly called after the adding of points is finished.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ryfajjh1/